# Can we add different class to first row and last row of view?

Tags: views, 8

Can we add different classes to first row and last row of view only ?

I have created a view of products listing in which i need to add unique class only in  first row and last row of view.

I need to implement it for creating different designs layout of each row. 
In drupal 7 i did it by using below code :

```
 end($rows);
$last = key($rows);
?>
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
<h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
<?php if ($id == $last): ?>
<?php $classes_array[$id] .= ' last-element'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
<?php print $row; ?>
 </div>
```

How we can do the same in drupal 8?

Comment: Dont downvote the question without having proper reason as its not a off topic?

Comment: You can use css to target first and last items you know? See pseudo selectors `:first-child` and `:last-child`

Comment: we are creating dynamic section not static it might have 10 or 15 rows

Comment: CSS doesn't care about that.

Comment: @Vikramfz16 how is `div:last-child` and `div:first-child` different than `div.first-item` and `div.last-item`?

Comment: and whats about rest part apart from first and last child?

Comment: What about them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would probably be fine with just doing this with css ( see Beebee's comment on your post), but I will answer the question.

You can use loop.first and loop.last in twig. Here is an example I used to make it work in a menu.

```
<ul class="menu">
    {% for item in items %}
        {%
            set classes = [
            'menu-item',
            item.is_expanded ? 'menu-item--expanded',
            item.is_collapsed ? 'menu-item--collapsed',
            item.in_active_trail ? 'menu-item--active-trail',
        ]
        %}
        {% if loop.first %}
            <li {{ item.attributes.addClass('first-element') }}>
               {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
               {% if item.below %}
                  {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
               {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endif %}
        {% if loop.last %}
            <li{{ item.attributes.addClass('last-element') }}>
                {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
                {% if item.below %}
                    {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
                {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% else %}
            <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
                {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
                {% if item.below %}
                    {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
                {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```